# Pause function causing issues in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to resume the game after pausing it, and it freezes the game, but after resuming, the game only gives you one key and the score is glitching between 0 and whatever score you actually have.

I tried using the `clearTimeout()` function to stop the function, store the timer, lives, score, and current key, however it seems to stuck on the one key I gave it.

This is the pause function:

```
function pause() {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
      if (event.key == 'Tab') {
        if (!isPaused) {
          isPaused = true;
          gameIsPlaying = false;
          window.currentKey = item
          window.currentScore = score
          window.currentTime = seconds
          window.currentLives = lives
          console.log(currentKey, currentScore, currentTime)
          clearTimeout(timerId);
          clearTimeout(updateLives);
          clearTimeout(ScoreUpdate);
          bars.forEach((bar) => {
            bar.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
          })
          AudioElement.pause();
        } else {
          isPaused = false;
          item = currentKey
          score = currentScore
          seconds = currentTime
          lives = currentLives
          game(item, seconds, lives, score);
          bars.forEach((bar) => {
            bar.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
          })
          AudioElement.play();
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b30osaLp/ (Tab to Pause game)

Edit:
I tried @code's solution in the comments.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
      if (event.key == 'Tab') {
        pause();
      }
  })
    function pause() {
        if (!isPaused) {
          isPaused = true;
          gameIsPlaying = false;
          clearTimeout(timerId);
          clearTimeout(updateLives);
          clearTimeout(ScoreUpdate);
          bars.forEach((bar) => {
            bar.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
          })
          AudioElement.pause();
        } else {
          isPaused = false;
          game();
          bars.forEach((bar) => {
            bar.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
          })
          AudioElement.play();
        }
    }
```

But it still is producing the same issue.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern leading to memory leaks and strange behavior. You're adding an event listener each time you call the function, but the previously registered event listeners don't get removed. I think you get the idea here. Instead, you can put your event listener _outside_ that function, then create a flag variable, e.g. `isPaused`, accessible in scope both by `pause()` and your event listener handler, then have your event listener handler check whether it's paused each time it's fired to decide whether to execute.

Comment: so in basic terms, just put the function inside the event listener?

Comment: I mean, separate the function and the event listener, and use a variable to tell the event listener whether it should execute or not, and change that variable when the `pause` function is called (and set it to `false` again inside the event listener).

Comment: @code how would i break the game function from the pause function?

Comment: @code i tried attempting what you told me, but it's still not working, check updated question

Comment: Looked at your fiddle code, and your entire code is a mess. There are multiple times that you add event listeners. Event listeners should be added _once_ unless removed. So every time you call `letter()`, two new event listeners are added. Every time `game()` is called, an event listener for pause is created. You need to refactor these from the `game()` method.

Comment: In order to understand what's happen, add `console.log(arguments.callee.name)` to all of your methods, and you will see how many times each method is called.

Comment: @RickardElimää I got a bunch of double "game" prints every time i pressed a key

Comment: What does this do? `function letter() {
    RandomLetterGUI.innerHTML = "Next Letter: " + item;
    bars.forEach((bar) => {
      bar.classList.remove("round-time-bar");
      bar.offsetWidth;
      bar.classList.add("round-time-bar");`

Comment: it picks a letter by random

Comment: I meant the `bar.classList.remove("round-time-bar");       bar.offsetWidth;       bar.classList.add("round-time-bar");` bit, which appears to remove a class, do nothing, then add the class back.

Comment: And it doesn't pick a letter at random, because the random generator is not in the function, hence the single letter, paused or not. I don't think this code can be recovered, so this bounty is misguided.

Comment: When you pause, you clear all the `timeout`s (which should be `interval`s), but you don't restart them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get your code to work, although I have re-written most of it.

I have removed all the extraneous features, such as `AudioElement` and the animated timer. I have simplified both your HTML and CSS.

You had 3 `setInterval`s, I have removed the `Score` and `Lives` intervals and replaced them by updating the relevant information when it is required do so.

I have collated all your event handlers into one per event type.

And I have used some functions, namely `bindElement` and `styleElement`, to tidy the code.

So now you can pause and restart the game! (Use `Q` - `TAB` has other uses and interferes with other code on the page).

```js
window.focus();

var paused, timerId;
var item, pickTime;
var seconds, lives, score;

const keys = ["W", "A", "S", "D", "Q", "ENTER"];

function bindElement(ref) {
  return document.getElementById(ref);
}

function styleElement(ref, clr, txt) {
  ref.style.backgroundColor = clr;
  ref.innerHTML = txt;
}

const LetterGUI = bindElement("Letter");
const TimerGUI = bindElement("Timer");
const LivesGUI = bindElement("Lives");
const ScoreGUI = bindElement("Score");
const W = bindElement("W");
const A = bindElement("A");
const S = bindElement("S");
const D = bindElement("D");
const PA = bindElement("playAgain");

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  var key = e.key.toUpperCase();

  if (!keys.includes(key)) return;

  if (key == 'Q') {
    if (!paused) {
      paused = true;
      clearTimeout(timerId);
    } else {
      paused = false;
      timerId = setTimeout(countdown, 0);
    }
    return;
  }

  if (key == "ENTER" && PA.style.visibility == "visible") {
    game();
    return;
  }

  if (key != item) {
    lives--;
    score -= 50;
    if (lives < 1) {
      gameOver();
      return;
    }
  } else {
    var elapsed = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) - pickTime;
    if (elapsed < 1.5) score += 500;
    else if (elapsed < 3) score += 350;
    else if (elapsed < 5) score += 150;
  }
  ScoreGUI.innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
  LivesGUI.innerHTML = "Lives: " + lives;

  if (key == "W")
    if (key == item) styleElement(W, 'lime', '');
    else styleElement(W, 'red', '');

  if (key == "A")
    if (key == item) styleElement(A, 'lime', '');
    else styleElement(A, 'red', '');

  if (key == "S")
    if (key == item) styleElement(S, 'lime', '');
    else styleElement(S, 'red', '');

  if (key == "D")
    if (key == item) styleElement(D, 'lime', '');
    else styleElement(D, 'red', '');

  letter();
}

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  var key = e.key.toUpperCase();
  if (key == "W") styleElement(W, 'white', 'W');
  if (key == "A") styleElement(A, 'white', 'A');
  if (key == "S") styleElement(S, 'white', 'S');
  if (key == "D") styleElement(D, 'white', 'D');
}

function letter() {
  item = keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
  LetterGUI.innerHTML = "Letter: " + item;
  pickTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
}

game();

function game() {
  paused = false;

  styleElement(W, 'white', 'W');
  styleElement(A, 'white', 'A');
  styleElement(S, 'white', 'S');
  styleElement(D, 'white', 'D')

  TimerGUI.style.color = "white";

  PA.style.visibility = "hidden";

  seconds = 20;
  lives = 3;
  score = 0;
  letter();
  ScoreGUI.innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
  LivesGUI.innerHTML = "Lives: " + lives;
  timerId = setTimeout(countdown, 0);
}

function countdown() {
  seconds--;
  if (seconds < 0) {
    gameOver();
    return;
  }
  if (seconds <= 5) TimerGUI.style.color = "red";
  if (seconds > 9) TimerGUI.innerHTML = "Time: " + seconds;
  else TimerGUI.innerHTML = "Time: 0" + seconds;
  timerId = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}

function gameOver() {
  clearTimeout(timerId);

  styleElement(W, 'red', '');
  styleElement(A, 'red', '');
  styleElement(S, 'red', '');
  styleElement(D, 'red', '')

  LetterGUI.innerHTML = "";
  TimerGUI.innerHTML = "";
  ScoreGUI.innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
  LivesGUI.innerHTML = "Lives: " + lives;

  PA.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #abcdef
}

.info {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px
}

.letter {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: green;
  font-family: "Courier New"
}
```

```html
<div id="Letter" class="info"></div>
<div id="Lives" class="info"></div>
<div id="Score" class="info"></div>
<div id="Timer" class="info"></div>
<table class="center">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td id="W" class="letter"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="A" class="letter"></td>
    <td id="S" class="letter"></td>
    <td id="D" class="letter"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span id="playAgain" class="footer">Press [Enter] to restart</span>
```

Comment: tysm so much, i wish it was it was before but the code is so much cleaner and actually works properly.

Answer (score 1):

#### Are you sure you intended to start the game with `setInterval(resetGame, 0)`?

That would repeatedly reset the game, every 0 ms.

Perhaps you meant to start it after a 0 ms timeout, i.e. once the interpreter became next free:

```
setTimeout(resetGame, 0);
```

When I change it in your fiddle, it seems to work as expected.

Comment: @gamer merch, If this worked, remember to mark this answer as accepted. 8-)

Comment: so if i make this simple change, i can pause and restart from where i left at without any issues? (I'll test it out later)

Comment: this solution didn't work, it doesn't really change anything at all.